# Calculating distance between 2 homography planes that have shared ground plane

Tags: opencv, image-processing, distance, homography

I think the easiest is to explain problem with image:
[image: two cubes]

I have two cubes (same size) that are laying on the table. One of their side is marked with green color (for easy tracking). I want to calculate the relative position (x,y) of left cube to the right cube (red line on the picture) in cube size unit.

Is it even possible? I know problem would be simple if those two green sides would have common plane - like top side of cube however I can't use that for tracking. I would just calculate homography for one square and multiply with other cube corner.

Should I 'rotate' homography matrix by multiplying with 90deegre rotation matrix to get 'ground' homography? I plan to do processing in smartphone scenario so maybe gyroscope, camera intrinsic params can be of any value.

Comment: you must calibrate the camera to the ground plane... to do that you must have 4 known points of the ground plane. if you want to measure in cube-size-units it would be the easiest to know 4 cube points that lie on the ground plane in pixel coordinates. unfortunately you see 3 in the image. maybe you can approx. 1 or just use 4 on the top-plane...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. 
Let's assume (or state) that the table is the z=0-plane and that your first box is at the origin of this plane. This means that green corners of the left box have the (table-)coordinates (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,1) and (1,0,1). (Your box has the size 1). 
You also have the pixel coordinates of these points. If you give these 2d and 3d-values (as well as the intrinsics and distortion of the camera) to cv::solvePnP, you get the relative Pose of the camera to your box (and the plane).

In the next step, you have to intersect the table-plane with the ray that goes from your camera's center through the lower right corner pixels of the second green box. This intersection will look like (x,y,0) and [x-1,y] will be translation between the right corners of your boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the information (camera intrinsics) you can do it the way FooBar answered.

But you can use the information that the points lie on a plane even more directly with a homography (no need to calculate rays etc):

Compute the homography between the image plane and the ground plane.
Unfortunately you need 4 point correspondences, but there are only 3 cube-points visible in the image, touching the ground plane.
Instead you can use the top-plane of the cubes, where the same distance can be measured.

first the code:

```
int main()
{
    // calibrate plane distance for boxes
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/BoxPlane.jpg");


    // if we had 4 known points on the ground plane, we could use the ground plane but here we instead use the top plane
    // points on real world plane: height = 1: // so it's not measured on the ground plane but on the "top plane" of the cube
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> objectPoints;  
    objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0)); // top front
    objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(1,0)); // top right
    objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,1)); // top left
    objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(1,1)); // top back

    // image points:
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> imagePoints;
    imagePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(141,302));// top front
    imagePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(334,232));// top right
    imagePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(42,231)); // top left
    imagePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(223,177));// top back

    cv::Point2f pointToMeasureInImage(741,200); // bottom right of second box


    // for transform we need the point(s) to be in a vector
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> sourcePoints;
    sourcePoints.push_back(pointToMeasureInImage);
    //sourcePoints.push_back(pointToMeasureInImage);
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(718,141));
    sourcePoints.push_back(imagePoints[0]);


    // list with points that correspond to sourcePoints. This is not needed but used to create some ouput
    std::vector<int> distMeasureIndices;
    distMeasureIndices.push_back(1);
    //distMeasureIndices.push_back(0);
    distMeasureIndices.push_back(3);
    distMeasureIndices.push_back(2);


    // draw points for visualization
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<imagePoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::circle(input, imagePoints[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
    }
    //cv::circle(input, pointToMeasureInImage, 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
    //cv::line(input, imagePoints[1], pointToMeasureInImage, cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 2);

    // compute the relation between the image plane and the real world top plane of the cubes
    cv::Mat homography = cv::findHomography(imagePoints, objectPoints);



    std::vector<cv::Point2f> destinationPoints;
    cv::perspectiveTransform(sourcePoints, destinationPoints, homography);

    // compute the distance between some defined points (here I use the input points but could be something else)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<sourcePoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "distance: " << cv::norm(destinationPoints[i] - objectPoints[distMeasureIndices[i]]) << std::endl; 

        cv::circle(input, sourcePoints[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
        // draw the line which was measured
        cv::line(input, imagePoints[distMeasureIndices[i]], sourcePoints[i], cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 2);
    }


    // just for fun, measure distances on the 2nd box:
    float distOn2ndBox = cv::norm(destinationPoints[0]-destinationPoints[1]);
    std::cout << "distance on 2nd box: " << distOn2ndBox << " which should be near 1.0" << std::endl;
    cv::line(input, sourcePoints[0], sourcePoints[1], cv::Scalar(255,0,255), 2);


    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output which I want to explain:

```
distance: 2.04674
distance: 2.82184
distance: 1
distance on 2nd box: 0.882265 which should be near 1.0
```

those distances are:

```
1. the yellow bottom one from one box to the other
2. the yellow top one
3. the yellow one on the first box
4. the pink one
```

so the red line (you asked for) should have a length of nearly exactly 2 x cube side length. But we have some error as you can see.

[image]

the better/more correct your pixel positions are before homography computation, the more exact your results.

You need a pinhole camera model, so undistort your camera (in real world application).

keep in mind too, that you could compute the distances on the ground plane, if you had 4 linear points visible there (that dont lie on same line)!